# php $_post variable comparison

Tags: php, http-post

I am trying to compare a post variable to a set string and it does not pass the logic but the print out matches. Is there something i'm missing?

```
 $testvar = stripcslashes($_POST['pass']);
 echo("test: ".$testvar);

 if( $testvar=='test'){
    echo("success");
 }
```

The above never returns success even though the print out test will show 'test'.

Comment: Better use `strcmp` function

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['pass']) && trim($_POST['pass']) === 'test') echo "success";`

Comment: If it's just a portion of the input you are searching for, you likely can just use `strpos()`. Hard to tell with what you have.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I never thought of using strcmp but it worked.